# MPI_Gather an array of structs in C

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to gather an array of structs using MPI_Gather.  I have created an derived datatype "mystruct" of one struct "Final" by using MPI_Type_contiguous (each elements is a double).  I then used this derived datatype in a simple MPI_Send and MPI_Receive to check that it was correct and it works.  Now, I want to use MPI_Gather to gather the entire array of structs, each having the derived datatype "mystruct".

Using Send and Recv, I know the MPI_Type_contiguous part is correct.  After MPI_Gather, MASTER just prints off zeros for the elements at the locations where there should have been the gathered information from the child processes.

```c
typedef struct{
        double Angle;
        double E_ODD;
        double OD_KE;
        double OD_L;
        double D_E;
}Final;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ierr = MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);

int totalnum_trajectories = file_size/9 //File that has xyz cartesian
                                        //coordinates for three atoms

int localnum_trajectories = totalnum_trajectories/numprocs;


Final worker_results[localnum_trajectory];
//Each processor does some analysis for its local number of trajectories
//and results go into worker_results buffer for each trajectory. 

//Create a datatype for the nth worker_results[n] struct
MPI_Datatype mystruct;
MPI_Type_contiguous(5,MPI_DOUBLE,&mystruct);
MPI_Type_commit(&mystruct);

//MASTER buffer: should get all local struct arrays from 
//children processors to one larger array of structs, equaling 
//the total number of trajectories
Final master_results[totalnum_trajectories];

ierr = MPI_Gather(worker_results, localnum_trajectory, mystruct, \
                  master_results, totalnum_trajectories, \
                  mystruct, MASTER, MPI_COMM_World);

//Do some I/O with MASTER; everything should be in master_results buffer

MPI_Finalize();
return(0);
}
```

After a correct MPI_Gather, MASTER should have all of the children results for proper I/O.

Comment: are `localnum_traj` and `totalnum_trajectories` the same ? please post a [MCVE] if you expect some more help.

Comment: No, localnum_traj is the number of trajectories each processor has.  And totalnum_trajectories is the total number of trajectories.  So, totalnum_trajectories = localnum_traj*number_of_processors.

Comment: I edited my code example for clarity.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  As the comment hinted at, MASTER's receive count should be the number of items from each processor (so localnum_trajectoires) and NOT the total number of counts from all processors. So everything is correct except the MPI_Gather MASTER count, which should be like

```c
ierr = MPI_Gather(worker_results, localnum_trajectories, mystruct,\
                  master_results, localnum_trajectories, mystruct,\
                  MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Cheers!!!